# HTML: how can I get my footer in the bottom of my website?

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm not a newbie to css and html, but totally not smart with php. Can someone tell me what to edit to have the grey bar at the bottom of my website (even when the content doesn't push the bar to the  bottom?

Here is the link to one a the pages containing a footer not in place (in Dutch)
Perhaps I looked over the problem to many times, but I can't find it (bed time?)

Note: I use a 23" screen at 1920 x 1080

Footer not [Footer bad](http://www.friesecomputerservice.nl/computerapk.html) good:

Footer [Footer also bad](http://www.friesecomputerservice.nl/backup-online.html) also bad

Comment: Try this link for sticky footers: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the footer to always be at the bottom of the browser window, try the [sticky CSS footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) code. ([More results on Google](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=sticky+footer&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=2289185d5cea093))

**EDIT:**

It seems that the first part of my answer is what you want, but I'm keeping this anyway.

If you want to keep the footer in view (even when there's more code) then you will need to use the following css:

```
#footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Note, that code may not work properly on mobile devices like iPad.

Comment: I want the footer to be a the bottom when the content is not large (high) enough to push the footer to the bottom.

Comment: Then use the sticky Footer code linked in my post. That's what you want.

Comment: Great answer, I hope it's easy to implement it in Joomla, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the html for the footer from firebug...

```
<div class="mf">
              <div style="color: rgb(142, 142, 128);" class="home-links-footer">
                <a href="/index.php">Home</a> | <a href="/contact-gegevens.html">Beveel ons aan!</a> | <a href="/onze-services.html">Onze Services</a> | <a href="/laptop-reparatie.html">Laptop Reparatie</a> | <a href="/tarieven.html">Onze Tarieven</a> | <a href="/contact-gegevens.html">Contact Gegevens</a> | <a href="#">Sitemap</a>
              </div>
              <div style="border-bottom: 1px dotted; margin: auto; color: rgb(142, 142, 128); padding-bottom: 3px; width: 700px;">
                Friese Computerservice - 8932 JZ Leeuwarden - <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="mailto:info@friesecomputerservice.nl"><span style="color: rgb(245, 127, 32); font-weight: bold;">info@friesecomputerservice.nl</span></a> - Tel. 058-8446628 Mob. 06-29594595
            </div>
        </div>
```